# Signed Request object no longer includes 'liked'

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to create a like gated page tab on facebook and no longer able to recieve the `'liked'` property in the signed request.

I know that facebook has announced they are banning this feature soon and I'm wondering if this is due to that?

I have several other apps with the exact same code live and they function fine. The only difference is that the appID etc is a new app created today. If I var dump the signed request object on the page it looks like so:

`array(4) { ["algorithm"]=> string(11) "HMAC-SHA256" ["issued_at"]=> int(1408704942) ["page"]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(15) "452083788149895" ["admin"]=> bool(true) } ["user"]=> array(3) { ["country"]=> string(2) "gb" ["locale"]=> string(5) "en_GB" ["age"]=> array(1) { ["min"]=> int(21) } } }`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is by design. It changed a few days ago. Like gating is not allowed anymore. And for all your old apps less 3 months from now liked will always be true.